# MySQL export with Java doesn't work

Tags: java, mysql, export

This is the code I created for exporting the database. The problem is, the file is not exported, and the code shows no error message.

```
public boolean exportDatabase(String fromServer,
                              String FileName,
                              String FilePath,
                              int ExportOpions) {
  try {     
    String dbName ="NMSAzzist";
    String dbUser = "root";
    String dbPass ="root";  
    String dumbPath = "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\bin\\";
    String executeCmd = dumbPath+"mysqldump -u "+dbUser+ "-p"+dbPass+" "+dbName+ "-r "+FilePath+ "";
    Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
    int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
    if (processComplete == 1) { // if values equal 1 process failed
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Backup Failed");//display message
    } else if (processComplete == 0) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\n Backup created Successfully..");
      // display message
    }
    return true;
  } catch (final Exception ex) {
    NmsLogger.writeErrorLog("Database Connection Failed ", ex.toString());
    NmsLogger.writeDebugLog(ex);
    return false;
  }
```

How can I export the database to a path specified in the variable `FilePath` in the name `FileName`? How can I solve the issue?

And BTW, can i use the following to import the same??

```
String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"mysql", databaseName, "-u" + userName, "-p" + password, "-e"  + FileName };
```

Comment: What is your file path? is it relative or an absolute? My wild guess is it is exporting to a wrong directory.

Comment: I think you should make `if(processComplete != 0){error} else {success}` instead of `if(processComplete==1)`, bcoz error-code returned may be other than 0 and 1.

Comment: @hims056: "the code shows no error message.". Gapchoos: Could you show the method invocation? I'm feeling it comes from the parameters. Have you tried to run the command (with the right parameters) in a shell?

Comment: The following code works with the parameters. and the export is successful.

Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\bin\\mysqldump -u root -proot mysql -r D:/backup.sql");

But i need to save the export file in a specific path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first try your executeCmd can run successfullly in db.
In your executeCmd is syntax error. Your code left file name in execution command in

```
String executeCmd = "/" + dumbPath + "mysqldump -u " + dbUser
                    + " -p" + dbPass + " " + dbName + " -r " + FilePath + "\\"
                    + FileName;
```

[Check the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

This works for me.

```
public class exportDataBase {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        exportDatabase("", "Sma_test.sql", "C:", 0);

    }

    public static boolean exportDatabase(String fromServer, String FileName,
            String FilePath, int ExportOpions) {
        try {

            String dbName = "dmsdev";
            String dbUser = "root";
            String dbPass = "root";

            String dumbPath = "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\bin\\";

            String executeCmd = "/" + dumbPath + "mysqldump -u " + dbUser
                    + " -p" + dbPass + " " + dbName + " -r " + FilePath + "\\"
                    + FileName;

            System.out.println(executeCmd);
            Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

            System.out.println("processComplete: " + processComplete);

            if (processComplete == 1) {// if values equal 1 process failed
                System.out.println("Backup failed");
            }

            else if (processComplete == 0) {
                System.out.println("Backup Success");

            }
            return true;
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Connection failed");
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you forget the Filename?

```
String executeCmd =dumbPath+"mysqldump -u "+dbUser+ "-p"+dbPass+" "+dbName+ "-r "+FilePath+"\\"+Filename"";
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it as :

```
// you did not give file name.
String executeCmd = "cmd " + dumbPath+"mysqldump -u "+dbUser+ "-p"+dbPass+" "+dbName+ "-r "+FilePath+ "\\" + filename;

// I tried running I am getting error code 13.
```

I think you should make :

```
if(processComplete != 0) {
   //error with error code
} else {
   //success
}
```

instead of

```
if (processComplete == 1) {// if values equal 1 process failed
      System.out.println("Backup failed");
}

else if (processComplete == 0) {
      System.out.println("Backup Success");
}
```

because error-code returned may be other than 0 and 1.

Suggestion : Use [Apache Commons exec API](http://commons.apache.org/exec/), this is more sophisticated than `Runtime.exec`.